# Value cannot be null error while communicating with the WCF service

Tags: .net, wcf, service, .net-4.6

I'm facing an issue while communicating with the WCF services.

***Message: An exception occurred trying to execute query on server: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: ns
Source: WCF library***

There are client libraries which help UI applications to connect to the WCF services. Recently, we have upgraded the service and applications to .NET framework 4.6 and since then, facing the issue

Any pointers would be of great help as this issue is killing my time.

Regards,
Satya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we use a class library to encapsulate the logic of invoking a WCF service, please move the configuration file of the System.Servicemodel section in the class library to the main project.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/deploying-a-wcf-library-project
Please check the whether the necessary configuration in the app.config has been moved to the main project, such as the connection string.
Alternatively, consider using the Channel Factory to hard-coded WCF configuration, then call the service.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.